# How to create a rolling time window with offset in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply some statistics on records within a time window with an offset. My data looks something like this:

```
                             lon        lat  stat  ...   speed  course  head
ts                                                 ...                      
2016-09-30 22:00:33.272  5.41463  53.173161    15  ...     0.0     0.0   511
2016-09-30 22:01:42.879  5.41459  53.173180    15  ...     0.0     0.0   511
2016-09-30 22:02:42.879  5.41461  53.173161    15  ...     0.0     0.0   511
2016-09-30 22:03:44.051  5.41464  53.173168    15  ...     0.0     0.0   511
2016-09-30 22:04:53.013  5.41462  53.173141    15  ...     0.0     0.0   511

[5 rows x 7 columns]
```

I need the records within time windows of 600 seconds, with steps of 300 seconds. For example, these windows:

```
start                     end
2016-09-30 22:00:00.000   2016-09-30 22:10:00.000
2016-09-30 22:05:00.000   2016-09-30 22:15:00.000
2016-09-30 22:10:00.000   2016-09-30 22:20:00.000
```

I have looked at Pandas [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) to do this. But it seems like it does not have the option to add the offset which I described above. Am I overlooking something, or should I create a custom function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve should be possible by combining `DataFrame.resample` with `DataFrame.shift`.

```py
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='T')
series = pd.Series(range(9), index=index)
df = pd.DataFrame(series)
```

That will give you a primitive timeseries (example taken from api docs [DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)).

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00  0                                                                                                                                                                        
2000-01-01 00:01:00  1                                                                                                                                                                        
2000-01-01 00:02:00  2                                                                                                                                                                        
2000-01-01 00:03:00  3                                                                                                                                                                        
2000-01-01 00:04:00  4                                                                                                                                                                        
2000-01-01 00:05:00  5                                                                                                                                                                        
2000-01-01 00:06:00  6                                                                                                                                                                        
2000-01-01 00:07:00  7                                                                                                                                                                        
2000-01-01 00:08:00  8
```

Now resample by your *step* size (see [DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas.DataFrame.shift)).

```py
sampled = df.resample('90s').sum()
```

This will give you non-overlapping windows of the *step* size.

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00   1                                                                                                                                                                       
2000-01-01 00:01:30   2                                                                                                                                                                       
2000-01-01 00:03:00   7                                                                                                                                                                       
2000-01-01 00:04:30   5                                                                                                                                                                       
2000-01-01 00:06:00  13                                                                                                                                                                       
2000-01-01 00:07:30   8
```

Finally, shift the sampled df by one step and sum with the previously created df. Window size being twice the step size helps.

```py
sampled.shift(1, fill_value=0) + sampled
```

This will yield:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00   1                                                                                                                                                                       
2000-01-01 00:01:30   3                                                                                                                                                                       
2000-01-01 00:03:00   9                                                                                                                                                                       
2000-01-01 00:04:30  12                                                                                                                                                                       
2000-01-01 00:06:00  18                                                                                                                                                                       
2000-01-01 00:07:30  21
```

There may be a more elegant solution, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is it